# Linear Diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So I was given a question to find if there is any integer solutions.

$6x + 15y = 79, x,y \in \Bbb Z$

Proof

$3(2x + 5y) = 79$ implies 3|79 which is absurd because no such x,y exist

Then I was given the same question but with the equation $5x + 15y = 130$

My proof

$5(x + 3y) = 130$ implies 5|130 which is 26. Do I just conclude that there are integer solutions. I'm not sure if I'm right on this but to me it does not seem correct.

Comment: You could give an example of integers $x$ and $y$ which satisfy the equation: for example, $x=2$, and $y=8$. That would tell you that there are integer solutions for sure, because you have found some!

Comment: So you concluded that $5|130$. Thus, dividing both sides by 5, you get $x+3y = 26$. Now you have a new problem: to find out if there are integers solutions to this equation, or not.

Comment: @wltrup wouldn't that just be 1|26?

Comment: @ChristopherW I meant divide both sides of $5(x+3y)=130$ by 5. Sorry, bad wording.

Answer (score 1):

In your proof with the equation $6x+15y=79$, you implicitly assumed that there were solutions, derived a contradiction, then deduced that your assumption (that there were solutions) was wrong. Hence there are no solutions. (That's a proof by contradiction.)

In your "proof" with the other equation, you assumed that there were solutions, but then derived a statement that was true. You cannot conclude anything at this point about solutions; you need more information. (Think of it this way: There might be another contradiction lurking out there that you haven't found yet.)